# If $ Ax=b $ has solution what about $ y $ in $ A^Ty=0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $ Ax=b $ has solution what about $ y $ in $ A^Ty=0 $? ($A$ is a $m \times n$ matriz).
Do we have them $ y^Tx = 0 $ or $ y^Tb = 0 $ and why ?

Should I explain using only the fact that $ b \in R^m $ and $ x \in R^n $ ? Or there is something more to say?

Comment: I wonder if you mean to ask another question. From your notation it looks like you may be asking about something related to Farkas' Lemma, but that wasn't what you actually said. i.e., if  $A$ is square invertible $(m=n)$ then there is no nontrivial solution to $A^Ty = 0$. Did you mean $A^Ty = b$

Comment: (Edit of previous comment) - $y^Tx$ only makes sense if $m=n$.

Comment: No, $A$ is a matrix representation of a linear system, $m$ equations and $n$ unknowns. So $A \in M_{m \times n} $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

We can't conlude in general since we need to distinguish the cases, as for example

- if $m=n$ and $Ax=b$ has solution for every $b$ then $A^Ty=0 \iff y=0$
- if $m=n$ and $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions for some $b$ then $A^Ty=0$ has infinitely many solutions
- ...and so on

Comment: Hello @Isham I've been suspended for 7 days!

Comment: +1 for your answer i know i am happy you're back

Comment: Could you explain further? I want to understand the ideas behind it, for the case $ m \neq n $.

Comment: Suppose $m>n$ then $Ax=b$ may have solution only for some particular $b$ and the solution is unique if $r=n$ otherwise the system has infinitely many solutions. In any case since r<m the system $A^Ty=0$ has infinitely many solutions.